# How can I buy options for an American Depositary Receipt (ADR) that trades over-the-counter (OTC)?

Tags: united-states, options, adr, options-exchanges

I looked up various data sources, but I was unable to find the option chain for a sponsored American Depositary Receipt (ADR) that happens to be traded over-the-counter (OTC).

For example, I could not find the option chain for Roche Holding Ltd ADR (OTC: [RHHBY](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/RHHBY/overview)), which is a sponsored ADR on the OTCQX tier that has significant daily volume.

Are there ways I can buy options on OTC ADRs?

Comment: You didn't find the option chain for RHYBY because it doesn't offer options.  Perhaps this might [help](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125639/if-a-put-option-is-delisted-before-its-price-drops-can-i-still-profit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every stock offers listed options. It's that simple. (By 'listed', I mean publicly traded. The company may still have employee stock options.)